# How do turn routing support for uwsgi on heroku?

Tags: heroku, pip, pcre, uwsgi, buildpack

I'm using uwsgi to serve my app on heroku. it seems routing isn't supported when deployed, because somehow uwsgi is built without regex capability. the log says:

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
```

I've enabled buildpacks from https://github.com/piotras/heroku-buildpack-pcre which seems to support installing pcre(perl compatible regular expressions) on heroku machines.

However uwsgi still fails to compile with pcre/routing:

```
>heroku run pip install -I uwsgi

.. wall of text ..

################# uWSGI configuration #################

locking = pthread_mutex
json = False
zlib = True
kernel = Linux
debug = False
capabilities = False
xml = libxml2
routing = False
ssl = True
execinfo = False
malloc = libc
filemonitor = inotify
pcre = False
plugin_dir = .
yaml = embedded
event = epoll
ifaddrs = True
timer = timerfd

############## end of uWSGI configuration #############
total build time: 23 seconds
*** uWSGI is ready, launch it with /app/.heroku/python/bin/uwsgi ***
```

how can I enable routing in uwsgi on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the uWSGI compile did not find the pcre source in the compile path and thus fails to add it in.